# MS SQL data to MS SQL by connection string

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, string

Good day I have

Server 1-

```
Server=10.000.00.01;
Database=DBNAMESOURCE
Table - tablename
;User Id=username;
Password=***;
```

And

Server 2 –

```
server=100.00.100.00;
database=dbnamedest;
table – tablename
```

I need get data from table on server1 to table on server2 To server 1 I connecting by different user as my current userlogin.
Do you have idea how I can retrieve data from server to server by different user… I try setup string like this but not work.. Usually I use this type of string but I have my user login in users section on the other servers.
I read https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/ but I can not fit.

```
/TABLESOURCE:username.tablename /SOURCETYPE:0 /TABLEDEST:tablename /DESTINATIONTYPE:0 /TRUNCATE:1 /PROC:1 /CSPARAMDB:server=100.00.100.00;database=dbnamedest;trusted_connection=true /CSSOURCE:“Server=10.000.00.01;Database=DBNAMESOURCE;User Id=username;Password=***;trusted_connection=true”/CSDEST:server=100.00.100.00;database=dbnamedest;trusted_connection=true /LDB:NO
```

Comment: I tried create SSIS but i can not connect to different server with different user as I running Visual Basic Studio.

Comment: Can you set up a [Linked Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine)?

Comment: No Linked server

Comment: seems to me what youre looking for is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607407/is-it-possible-to-copy-the-data-in-a-remote-mssql-table-to-a-local-table

Comment: Does either of the servers allow SQL Server authentication?